# read an Object(customized) from ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, client-server, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

So, I don't know why the Client part of my project give me this type of error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Mining.FrequentPatternMiner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at JabberClient.main(JabberClient.java:81)`

In the Server part, I cast the FrequentPatternMiner variable and then i give it to the ObjectOutputStream

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

FrequentPatternMiner fpMiner=new FrequentPatternMiner(dataTarget, minsup);  
fpMiner.salva("FP_"+nameFile+"_minSup"+minsup+".dat");
System.out.println("Frequent Patterns \n"+fpMiner);

out.flush();
out.writeObject((Object)fpMiner);
```

In the Client part, i do this

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

Object fpMiner=in.readObject();
(((ObjectInput)in).readObject());
System.out.println(fpMiner);
```

How would I fix my code? Can you help me?

Comment: You are trying to deserialize a class it doesn't have.  I suggest you create a jar with all the objects to share between the server and the client and make sure you have the same version of that jar at both ends.

Comment: How i can create this jar?

Comment: I would use `maven`, but you can use `ant` or the `jar` command, or a plugin in your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, but your premise isn't. You've said, that the class "`FrequentPatternMiner` must be unknown for the client". With that premise you can't serialize the class as you did, because serialization only transfers the data of the object and *not* it's implementation.
You might want to look into DataTransferObjects (which has to be known on both client and server) or use a simple array to transfer the object.

**Example using a simple array as "DTO"**

Server:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

// The following line assumes that dataTarget and minsup are types 
// that are serializable and known to the client
Object[] objArray = new Object[] { dataTarget, minsup };

out.flush();
out.writeObject(objArray);
```

Client:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

Object[] objArray = (Object[])in.readObject();
System.out.println(objArray);

// FrequentPatternMiner must still known to the client, if you need more than 
// the constructor arguments (like methods of the FrequentPatternMiner) Object.
FrequentPatternMiner fpMiner=new FrequentPatternMiner(objArray[0], objArray[1]);
```

### Further Idea

If you don't want that FrequentPatternMiner implementation/class is known to the client, you can try "Remoting" or "Remote Procedure Calls" (RPC). This is an advanced subject and there are a lot of libraries out there (and platforms) that provide this functionallity. They do basically this:

- You need an Interface for the Class on the client (like `interface IPatternMiner { void doMine() }`
- You connect server and client (depends on the library on how to do this) and obtain an instance of `IPatternMiner`
- You call a method on the interface and the implementation gets executed on the server (with the parameters pased in from the client). Note that file operations write on the file system on the server

Comment: thanks for the answer, can u give me an example? I have to implements DataTransferObject or i can only import in both my project?

how i can use a simple array?

Comment: Has ```FrequentPatternMiner``` methods that should be executed on the client? Then there is no way (read simple way) without letting the client known the class within a jar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that `FrequentPatternMiner` is not on your classpath.

What you can do is `ctrl+t` on Eclipse and look for FrequentPatternMiner to know what is the jar containing this class. Then ensure that your project is referencing this class.

If you are using maven you can use `mvm dependency:tree` goal to know if your project contain this jar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the FrequentPatternMiner jar is in the Server project and the Client should not have this class

Comment: @user3786467 the application giving that error surely doesn't have the jar on his class path.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to Object doesn't have any magical properties. Everything can be cast to Object. It doesn't change the fact that what is written to the object stream is a FrequentPatternMiner, and if that class isn't available at the receiver, this exception will result.

Solution: deploy the class.

Similarly, casting an ObjectInputStream to ObjectInput accomplishes precisely nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to tyecast.

```
System.out.println((FrequentPatternMiner )fpMiner);
```

Else how would the client know class of the Object that is being deserialized. Note it is not necessary to typecast just for using it in `sysout`. It will print using Objects `toString()` method.

Though your Exception says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

You need to add this class on the client side too. Lastly check that `serialVersionUID` is same for the class in server and client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ;). The FrequentPatternMiner class must be unknown for the client. I have made two different project, the Server and the Client one. In the Server i put different packages that contains all the classes, in the Client i put only the part for the connection with the server part

Comment: `System.out.println((FrequentPatternMiner )fpMiner);` the typecast is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah but will not make much sense as Objects `toString()` will be invoked.

Comment: The OP doesn't need to typecast. The object already is of that class. Your remarks about Object.toString() are nonsensical.

Comment: That's not 100% correct. If FrequentPatternMiner implements toString, than it's toString implementation will be called regardless of the cast. So ```class Untitled {
 public static class Blob {
  public String toString() {
   return "mine";
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Blob b = new Blob();
  System.out.println(b);
  Object c = b;
  System.out.println(c);
 }
}``` return the same.